# Specifying return type

Tags: c#, generics

I have the psuedocode

```
T foo<T>(string bar) 
{
 if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
 {
   return bar;
 }
...
```

Although the code doesnt really make much sense , is it possible to get something similar to above working?

Ive tried `return (T)bar` and `return bar as T` to no avail.

edit: Apologies, pseudocode corrected.

Comment: Because you have a void method, or am I missing something?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What happens after that if?

Comment: your method is typed as returning void, what are you trying to return?

Comment: Your return type is void and you're trying to return something?

Comment: If your method is `void` then you're not going to return anything. Can you provide an example that more closely matches what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: It's not so much that your code doesn't make sense, it's that it's really not at all clear what you're trying to do. What's `strResponse` ? What *values* do you want to return, and under what circumstances?

Comment: Agree with all above, `strResponse` is nowhere to be found, your method is `void` and we don't know what you want.  We can help, but you need a very clear example and description of what you want it to do.

Comment: @All sorry, my psuedocode was too rushed and made zero sense

Comment: You should at least explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve. This specified function can only be called if the caller specifies the T explicitly, which makes it rather pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that:

```
T foo<T>(string bar) 
{
 if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
 {
   return (T)(object)bar;
 }
...
```

But if you're doing something different depending on the type of T, you should probably reconsider your design... perhaps generics are not the best option for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jsobo: not sure who either, but the original code in the answer showed a return of 'void', that's probably why someone downvoted (the editted form is now correct).

Comment: would return (T)(bar as object) not be better?

Answer (score 1):

You pseudo-method is `void`, so it doesn't expect a return value.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to test the type properly 
for example

```
if (T.GetType().Equals(typeof(String))) {}
```

also what is it that you are truly trying to do..? are you familiar with how to use Generics..?

Comment: `T` is a type parameter, `typeof(T)` is correct, not `T.GetType()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the return type - not `void`

```
T foo<T>(string bar){
 if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)){
   return (T)(object)bar;
 }
}
```

But this does not make any sense - why would you do this? Typically, your signature would look something like:

```
void foo<T>(T bar){
 if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)){
   // do something useful with bar
 }
}
```

...in the above example, modify `void` to return whatever is the result of *something useful*.